# OpenSSL 1_1_0e BN_print_fp not working

Tags: c, openssl

I am using Openssl 1_1_0e and I cannot figure out what's wrong with my code:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>

int main(){

    BIGNUM          *bne = NULL; 
    unsigned long   e = RSA_F4;
    RSA             *r = NULL;

    bne = BN_new();
    BN_set_word(bne,e);
    r = RSA_new();

    BIGNUM *n = NULL;
    BIGNUM *d = NULL;
    RSA_get0_key((const RSA *) r, (const BIGNUM **) &n, NULL, (const BIGNUM **) &d);

    BN_print_fp(stdout, n);
    RSA_free(r);
    BN_free(bne);

    return  0;
}
```

Valgrind says there was invalid read of size 4:

```
==8066== Invalid read of size 4
==8066==    at 0x4EF603E: BN_print (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==8066==    by 0x4EF662D: BN_print_fp (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/library/lib/libcrypto.so.1.1)
==8066==    by 0x40093B: main (in /home/roman/Dropbox/uni/RSA/my_work/sharedLibraryTest)
==8066==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

What is wrong with my code? It looks fine to me.

Comment: why the **casts** - it is already hard enough to not shoot yourself in the foot without explicit casting...

Comment: You mean the `(const BIGNUM **)` part? It wouldn't work without that since it is not `const`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes! `const BIGNUM *n`.

Comment: That would make `n` constant, but not `&n`. Am I wrong?

Comment: umm you're now doubly wrong. `&n` is *address of `n` and it cannot ever change for any variable for the lifetime of that variable `n` wouldn't be constant; that would be `BIGNUM *const n`.

Comment: If I remove the casts: this is one of the compile warnings: ` warning: passing argument 2 of ‘RSA_get0_key’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
expected ‘const BIGNUM ** {aka const struct bignum_st **}’ but argument is of type ‘BIGNUM ** {aka struct bignum_st **}’`

Comment: did you try `const BIGNUM *n, *d;` Notice that `const BIGNUM *` is what `BN_print_fp` expects too: `int BN_print_fp(FILE *fp, const BIGNUM *a);`. Since you're not to modify the BNs returned by `RSA_get0_key` that's the correct definition.

Comment: I forgot to make `n` const as well, sorry, I am an idiot. Now it works as you say - without explicit casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this piece of code directly because I don't have `RSA_get0_key` but [OpenSSL documentation](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/RSA_get0_key.html) says that

> The `n`, `e` and `d` parameters can be obtained by calling RSA_get0_key(). **If they have not been set yet, then `*n`, `*e` and `*d` will be set to NULL. Otherwise, they are set to pointers to their respective values.** These point directly to the internal representations of the values and therefore should not be freed by the caller.

You're calling `RSA_new();` but there is nothing *setting* these BIGNUM's in the RSA object - as far as I can read `RSA_new()` doesn't do it - how could it, because generating them takes a loooong time. Thus `n` is set to `NULL` pointer; and the error comes when `BN_print_fp` attempts to read a member of the `BIGNUM` structure at offset 16. (I.e. `*(uint32_t*)((char*)NULL + 16)`)

---

Minimal example:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
int main(void) {
    BN_print_fp(stdout, NULL);
}
```

Compile with `gcc test.c -lssl -lcrypto`, then use `valgrind`:

```
% valgrind ./a.out
[...]
==16062== Invalid read of size 4
==16062==    at 0x4EFA5F4: BN_print (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==16062==    by 0x4EFA743: BN_print_fp (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0)
==16062==    by 0x108745: main (in /home/user/tmp/a.out)
==16062==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
[...]
```

Comment: *"I cannot test this piece of code directly because I don't have RSA_get0_key..."* - Try `git clone https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git`. The default branch is 1.1.0.

Comment: @jww yeah, well I think I didn't need to test it :)